# Change /profile end-point generated when using data-rest package

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When using the package spring-boot-starter-data-rest Spring automatically creates some end-points named /profile for Alps, as follows:

```
2017-03-08 22:09:12.737  INFO 8663 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile],methods=[OPTIONS]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ProfileController.profileOptions()
2017-03-08 22:09:12.738  INFO 8663 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile],methods=[GET]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ProfileController.listAllFormsOfMetadata()
2017-03-08 22:09:12.738  INFO 8663 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/schema+json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.JsonSchema> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySchemaController.schema(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2017-03-08 22:09:12.738  INFO 8663 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile/{repository}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/alps+json]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.alps.AlpsController.alpsOptions()
2017-03-08 22:09:12.738  INFO 8663 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/alps+json || */*]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.alps.AlpsController.descriptor(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
```

The problem is that I have a `RestRepository` entitled profile as well, so I'm going to use those end-points as well.

Question is:
how to change the end-point to some other thing? Or even take it off.

Comment: I won't see this in my log, but they are there (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76036083/why-is-this-webmvc-profilecontroller-being-exposed-and-interfering-with-my-stati)

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled upon the same issue 4 years later, per [this bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/issues/1480) it appears there's a partial workaround to at least disable the functionality of the endpoints, though the /profile url is still exposed.

Comment: I want to disable ALPS but I am not able to find RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter in org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config

I am using spring-boot-starter-data-rest 2.6.1
And included spring-data-rest-webmvc 3.6.0

Please let me know

Comment: @java_dev I feel ya.. did you solve this problem somehow? Maybe you can answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76036083/why-is-this-webmvc-profilecontroller-being-exposed-and-interfering-with-my-stati

Answer (score 1):

Add following to application.properties file.

`endpoints.enabled=false`

This will disable all public endpoints provided by spring/actuator.

`management.context-path=/public`
This will append /public to all spring provided endpoints such as /profile.

Comment: It didn't worked.. The profile end-points still there as they were.