# Why is this WebMvc ProfileController being exposed and interfering with my static website?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm hosting an Angular application inside a Spring Boot application.

Accessing routes like

- https://localhost:8081/sign-in
- https://localhost:8081/invalid-url (redirects to `PageNotFoundComponent`)

is not an issue. However, if I access somthing below `/profile`:

- https://localhost:8081/profile
- https://localhost:8081/profile/settings

I'll get an actual JSON responses, preventing the actual web-client to be loaded (see animation below).

After setting the debug-level on `root` to `DEBUG`, I saw the following:

```
:  GET "/profile", parameters={}
:  Mapped to org.springframework...ProfileController#listAllFormsOfMetadata()
```

and indeed, the code reaches `org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ProfileController#listAllFormsOfMetadata()` and I don't know how to disable this behavior or why this endpoint is being exposed in the first place.

Since Spring is exposing JPA-Repositories on default, I am already disabling this default behavior like so:

```java
@Configuration
public class SpringRestConfiguration implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(
        RepositoryRestConfiguration config, CorsRegistry cors
    ) {
        config.disableDefaultExposure();
    }
}
```

How can I fix (disable) this behavior?

### Animation

[image]

### See also

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/issues/1480

Comment: What does the controller method that serves /profile and /profile/settings look like? Pls include imports, and class and method annotations. What does your security configuration look like?

Comment: @JohnWilliams Well, there is no controller for these routes on the Spring Boot server. That's the weird part. I've added the `SecurityConfiguration` to my question.

Comment: is this link helpful for you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50001285/angular-routing-doesnt-work-after-deploy-into-a-springboot-application

Comment: Understood. You are expecting to serve an angular page located in resources from /profile/settings, not a pure REST response. Perhaps there is something built in by SpringBoot that serves rest on /profile (profile is a very spring thing). Try renaming route in Angular to something very unlikely, eg /happydays to test the theory and whether the resourcehandler is behaving correctly. Your angular stuff is built/webpacked before dropping in resources/static?

Comment: @JohnWilliams I've already tested this by visiting something like https://localhost:8081/sign-in or an invalid URL - it's only `/profile` that I know of right now which gives a JSON response. My guess is that is has something to do with JPA but I have no idea what it could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution (Part 1)

In order to be able to refresh the Angular web-application at all, I had to add a resource handler which resolves non-existing/readable resources like so:

```java
@Configuration
public class StaticWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    /**
     * This is used to make page refreshes possible for the Angular App which runs on the root.
     */
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        PathResourceResolver pathResourceResolver = new PathResourceResolver() {
            @Override
            protected Resource getResource(
                    @NotNull String resourcePath,
                    @NotNull Resource location
            ) throws IOException {
                Resource requestedResource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);
                boolean isValid = requestedResource.exists() && requestedResource.isReadable();
                return isValid ? requestedResource : new ClassPathResource("/static/index.html");
            }
        };

        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
                .resourceChain(false)
                .addResolver(pathResourceResolver);
    }    
}
```

### Solution (Part 2)

Unfortunately, this is not enough for my particular case as the web-application has routes at and below `/profile`.

Spring Boot, for some reason, exposes some additional endpoints. Unfortunately, it appears that we cannot disable them programmatically (or at least not to my knowledge). The solution that *should* work (see further down below) does not work.

What we're left with is a workaround.

#### The workaround

This won't be an option for everyone but in my case it is. So far this will show the desired behavior.

```yaml
spring:
  data:
    rest:
      # Spring Boot somehow exposes endpoints which interfere without web-application
      # It's not possible to work around this right now other than setting the base-path
      # of @BasePathAwareController classes to something else
      base-path: "/api-ignore-1337-only-took-me-one-day-to-figure-42"
```

#### The solution that should work and *might* work someday

```java
@Override
public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(
        RepositoryRestConfiguration config, CorsRegistry cors
) {
    // Disable Alps resources
    config.getMetadataConfiguration().setAlpsEnabled(false);
}
```

#### Related issue on GitHub

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/issues/1480